# MySQL query to count from a table based on location with reference to other table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT s.id, u.name, de.name,
SUM(dp.destination_id = 1 AND l.liked = 1) AS tokyo_count,
SUM(dp.destination_id = 2 AND l.liked = 1) AS osaka_count,
SUM(dp.destination_id = 3 AND l.liked = 1) AS hokkaido_count
FROM `t0120_swipe_set` s, `t0121_swipe_log` l, `t0111_destination_photo` dp, `t0110_destination` d,`t0101_user` u, 
`t0110_destination` de
    WHERE s.id = 8
        AND s.id = l.set_id
            AND l.destination_photo_id = dp.id
                AND dp.destination_id = d.id
                    AND s.user_id = u.id
                        AND s.suggested_destination_id = de.id;

t0110_destination
    id
    name
    swipe_count

t0111_destination_photo
    id
    destination_id

t0120_swipe_set
    id
    user_id
    suggested_destination_id

t0121_swipe_log
    set_id
    user_id
    destination_photo_id
    liked
```

These are my queries and table structure, 
what i am trying to get is the total of like count on each destination by each swipe set.
This query is executable, however, it always return only one record.
let say, i want to select from all swipe set, instead of s.id = 8.

ps. I tried IN, but instead, the SUM is messed up, and it also return only on row.

Anyway that i can solve this problem? 
Thank you

Comment: show some sample data here and expected result.

Comment: `SELECT s.id, u.name, de.name,
SUM(dp.destination_id = 1 AND l.liked = 1) AS tokyo_count,
SUM(dp.destination_id = 2 AND l.liked = 1) AS osaka_count,
SUM(dp.destination_id = 3 AND l.liked = 1) AS hokkaido_count
FROM `t0120_swipe_set` s
INNER JOIN `t0121_swipe_log` l ON s.id = l.set_id
INNER JOIN `t0111_destination_photo` dp ON l.destination_photo_id = dp.id
INNER JOIN `t0110_destination` d ON dp.destination_id = d.id
INNER JOIN `t0101_user` u ON s.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN `t0110_destination` de ON s.suggested_destination_id = de.id
GROUP BY S.ID`
Just try above code.Hope this helps.

Comment: @SagarGangwal: oh wow.. 
It works. Thank you.
But compare to  <b>SUM(CASE WHEN p.`destination_id` = 1 THEN l.`liked` END) AS `tokyo_count`<b> using case, which one is better in term of performance? I would like to know it.
Thanks.
As i am newbie in mysql

Comment: `CASE WHEN` will works fast,as far as my knowledge concern.Still you can try with `CASE WHEN` and Note down the execution time for same bunch of records.
it will give you exact timing and you can choose better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.id, u.name, de.name,
SUM(dp.destination_id = 1 AND l.liked = 1) AS tokyo_count,
SUM(dp.destination_id = 2 AND l.liked = 1) AS osaka_count,
SUM(dp.destination_id = 3 AND l.liked = 1) AS hokkaido_count
FROM `t0120_swipe_set` s
INNER JOIN `t0121_swipe_log` l ON s.id = l.set_id
INNER JOIN `t0111_destination_photo` dp ON l.destination_photo_id = dp.id
INNER JOIN `t0110_destination` d ON dp.destination_id = d.id
INNER JOIN `t0101_user` u ON s.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN `t0110_destination` de ON s.suggested_destination_id = de.id
GROUP BY S.ID
```

Just tried above code.
Hope this will helps.

Comment: oh wow.. It works. Thank you. But compare to <b>SUM(CASE WHEN p.destination_id = 1 THEN l.liked END) AS tokyo_count<b> using case, which one is better in term of performance? I would like to know it. Thanks. As i am newbie in mysq